# Put graphics behind the text in the same window of SapScript

Tags: forms, abap, sapscript

I need to put a .bmp of a stamp **behind** some text in a sapscript form - **in one window**.
I've uploaded the bitmap of the stamp by using the **se78**, I uploaded it as standard text.

I'm already done some testing. This is what I got so far:

```
/:      INCLUDE Z_ADRS_SIGN_CN30 OBJECT TEXT ID ADRS LANGUAGE EN
/:      INCLUDE 'Z_SIGN_STAMP_CN30' OBJECT TEXT ID ST LANGUAGE EN
```

This is working, but the stamp gets printed **under** the text.
If I switch the code-lines, the stamp gets printed **above** the text.

---

*Now to my question:* Is there a way to print the stamp **behind** the text **in one window** ? And if yes, how?

Comment: Why do you need to have both in one window?

Comment: Because the text(sign) is used to be at the end of the purchase order, and at runtime I don't know the absolute position of the end(because it varies). I think I need the absoulte position to put the stamp in another window behind that sign. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to print a scanned signature on purchase orders, but that's none of my business... Which options did you use when uploading the graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but it's better to use SmartForms for this, because it can print watermarks natively.

For SapScript:

1. Create SO10 text element and insert graphics object there

[image]

2. Put this statement into your text element

   ```
   BITMAP 'YOURBMP' OBJECT GRAPHICS ID BMAP TYPE BCOL.
   ```
3. In the `MAIN` window of your form put these statements

   ```
   INCLUDE BMP OBJECT TEXT ID ST.
   NEW-WINDOW.
   ```

The key point here is `NEW-WINDOW` statement. It opens new window oon the page explicitly and prints all consecutive SapScript statements in the new window.

Comment: Hi, I've tested it in a testform, where only one so 10 text is included and the graphic as shown above. But it prints only the part **before** the `NEW-WINDOW`.

Comment: Do you have any statements after `NEW-WINDOW`? Give the full code of your SSCRIPT form.